# Validate fields from one table to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

**The problem:**

I have 1 table of aprox **5000 rows** called **imported_cities**

I have 1 table of aprox **800 000 rows** called **postal_codes** containing postal codes cities

I need to **validate each distinct city from imported_cities against the cities in postal codes table** based on city name and its province. See tables structure below.

If they **match exactly** (yes, exactly. The rest of cities are manually validated) I have to **update a column on imported_city** and 
enter both **city from imported_cities** and **city from postal_codes** (side by side) into a **third table** called **imported_cities_equiv**

**What I have tried:**
Adding indexes to tables and make query below. **It takes forever...** :(

```
explain SELECT DISTINCT ic.destinationCity, pc.city FROM (imported_cities ic, postalcodes pc)
WHERE LOWER(ic.destinationCity) = LOWER(pc.city)
```

the result

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE ip index NULL  company_city 478 NULL 4221 Using index; Using temporary 
1 SIMPLE pc index NULL city_prov 160 NULL 765407 Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block...
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `postalcodes`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `postalcodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `province` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `provinceISO` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(17,13) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(17,13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `city_prov` (`city`,`provinceISO`)
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `imported_cities`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imported_cities` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `companyName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `destinationCity` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `destinationProvince` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `equivCity` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `minAmount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `company_city` (`companyName`,`destinationCity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci     AUTO_INCREMENT=7933 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `imported_cities_equiv`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imported_cities_equiv` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imported_city` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `pc_city` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `province` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=149 ;
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: additionally your query is taking forever because it is basically doing a table scan on `pc` you have ~800K rows and its looking at 765407, besides that being multiplied by the `ip` that it is looking at 4221 ...You have to add the proper indexes, join on an ON clause to properly establish the relation between the tables, and/or refine your search by adding addition where clause parameters....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you want to get your information is:

```
SELECT ip.*, (pc.city is not null) as exact match
FROM imported_prices ip left join
     postalcodes pc
     on LOWER(ip.destinationCity) = LOWER(pc.city)  and
        lower(ip.province) = lower(pc.province);
```

However, this will have really bad performance.  Getting rid of the `lower()` would help:

```
SELECT ip.*, (pc.city is not null) as exact match
FROM imported_prices ip left join
     postalcodes pc
     on(ip.destinationCity) =(pc.city)  and
       (ip.province) = (pc.province);
```

Because then you can add an index on `postalcodes(city, province)`.

If you cannot use remove `lower()`, then alter the table to add new columns and put the lower-case values in those columns.  Then build an index on the new columns and use them in the join.

Comment: "exact match" is not working on MySQL. I have tried this: SELECT ip.destinationCity, (pc.city is not null) as city 
FROM imported_prices ip left join
     postalcodes pc
     on BINARY ip.destinationCity = BINARY pc.city and
       (ip.destinationProvince) = (pc.province); but the query took more than 2 minutes to return 1000 rows

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for pointing me on the right direction.

Some changes have been made following your advices:

- added indexes on imported_cities table on destinationCity and destinationProvince columns
- added indexes on postalcodes table on city and provinceISO columns
- JOIN clause have only one side upper since the field ic.destinationCity is already in uppercase
- limit query by province on WHERE for performance

The final SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pc.city, pc.provinceISO
FROM  postalcodes pc
    LEFT JOIN imported_cities ic
     ON upper(pc.city) = ic.destinationCity AND
     pc.provinceISO = ic.destinationProvince
     WHERE ic.destinationProvince = 'QC';
```

AND the EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  pc  ref province    province    8   const   278115  Using index condition; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE  ip  ref destinationCity,destinationProvince destinationCity 386 func    1   Using index condition; Using where; Distinct
```

Going forward I can now construct the INSERT query on PHP and make one INSERT query to insert all equivalent cities on the 3rd table. Thank you all.

Comment: curious, how long does that query take to run now? and will these tables size ever grow or are they static rows?

Comment: The postalcodes grows once a year but not much. The imported cities can grow with max 1000 per year but, in general, they are static tables. The query takes 1-3 sec. Good enough.

Comment: how often will this query be run though?  1-3 seconds may seem `good enough` now but at scale you will need to shave seconds off that...

Comment: Agree but the query runs 4 times a year when the new cities are imported.